# Copying three JS rendered canvas to another canvas fails on desktop Safari

Tags: safari, three.js, html5-canvas

I need to copy a canvas rendered with three.js to another canvas by using the drawImage method of the canvas context.

```
ctx.drawImage(renderer.domElement, 0, 0);
```

It works like expected on Chrome and Firefox but doesn't work at all on my desktop Safari. I tried to specify the texture format but it didn't make any difference. Anyone knows the trick?

Here's a codepen with the three.js script.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNvzMJ

Comment: 1. What does "doesn't work" mean? 2. The codepen renders properly for me on OS X 10.10.4 / Safari 8.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

This code works on safari but it flips the image upside down and the framerate goes down by 50% so it's definitely not ideal.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLqmRO

```
    var gl = renderer.getContext();

    var width = renderer.domElement.width;
    var height = renderer.domElement.height;

    var size = width * height * 4;
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(size);
    var image = ctx.createImageData(width, height);

    gl.readPixels(0, 0, width, height, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);

    for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        image.data[i] = pixels[i];
    }

    ctx.putImageData(image, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `canvas.getImageData`?

```
var width = renderer.domElement.width;
var height = renderer.domElement.height;
var imgData = gl.getImageData(0, 0, width , height);
ctx.drawImage(imgData, 10, 70);
```